# Is Dave Skylark's line containing "Mangia. We're the people. Give us the sh-t." a reference to something?

Tags: dialogue, reference, the-interview

I've noticed a lot of movie and pop culture references in The Interview (2014). I was wondering if Dave Skylark's line here is a reference to something:

> Aaron: We could be doing something positive. We could be having on
>   authors, activists, politicians.
>
> Dave: That's what people want. "Give us some shit. Mangia. We're the
>   people. Give us the shit. Mangia, mangia, mangia."

Note: I'm not sure if "mangia" is the proper spelling. [Searching for "mangia" shows links to Italian restaurants](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=mangia). While [Wikipedia's article for "Mangia"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mangia) is about a video game. I'm not sure if either is related.

Answer (score 4):

Though my girlfriend disagrees, I am fairly confident this is reference to [Salò, the 120 Days of Sodom (1975)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sal%C3%B2,_or_the_120_Days_of_Sodom), an Italian art film that depicts characters eating feces.

Here's a YouTube link to the [specific scene](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3GVV7L66xh4).

Comment: I should not have seen that,I should not have seen that !

Answer (score 0):

This is also a reference to The Sopranos where, after a long night gambling and drinking, Paulie Walnuts exclaims on their way to the diner in the early AM, I am going to "mange and sleep for the next 18 hours."

I think this is how the Amazon Prime CC spelled it. I will try to follow up with a specific episode number. It happens when they are dropping Tony Blundetto (Steve Buscemi) off at work at Kim's laundry.

Answer (score -1):

I just think its meant to be funny, I know that mangia means 'to eat' in Italian.

Is he just jokingly trying to say we the people just want the shock value of the shit. the tabloid shit. I think he by saying 'give us some shit' it just means more of the same shock value headlines they had been doing.

Answer (score -1):

Its absolutely 100% a reference to "Salò, the 120 Days of Sodom" (1975). The irony is that "The Interview" no different..just more of the same crap shoveled into our faces :)) and we continue to eat it.

Comment: Welcome to the site. If you have reference to what you are talking about, you should add it. If not, explain more why you believe this is so. Adding some context and fleshing out your answer will gain better acceptance of your answer.